# Custom(ish) jQuery accordion menu buggy in IE7

Tags: jquery, css

I have an accordion style menu which seems to be working fine in IE8, Firefox and Chrome (although it probably isn't as smooth as it could be), but in IE7 or IE8 Compatibility mode, it seems to be totally erratic, and I'm at a loss as to what the problem is. Can anyone offer any pointers? The site is [here](http://qvs.org.uk)
 Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your site gives an error when I go to it in IE7. I see the problem that causes that, but I'm unsure if it is affecting the menu.

You are tring to make an input have rounded corners with the command:

```
$('input#search_button').corner('5px right');
```

You cannot corner an input in IE. Try putting the input into a div and running corner on that.
[Here's a link to a forum that talks about this problem](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-corner-js-problem-in-ie-and-opera)

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for pointing that out - i was having the issue with the menu before i added that, so it must be caused elsewhere. Out of interest, did you experience a problem with the menu? I only seem to get it intermittently in IE on the one machine

Comment: @franko75 It worked sometimes, but other times you got stuff like this: http://imgur.com/ag9pu.jpg . That can't be good. I'd recommend going with bpeterson76's advice and using jQueryUI.

Comment: Yeah that's no good at all. Hmm, I have a few levels deep in the menu and each submenu is also an accordion within it's parent. I'll have a look at UI to see how easy it will be with this type of menu (hopefully straightforward!)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a ton of time to go through your code, but consider using the new(er) JQuery UI Accordion which is built into Jquery UI as of the latest version.  It can be seen here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

It's tested in all browsers, installs extremely quickly, and can be styled using Themeroller.  Best of all in my mind is that once you install the code for JqueryUI, you can re-use its functionality over and over for the most common UI tasks as opposed to calling a bunch of "custom" jquery files and adding http requests.

Based on my experience with Accordion, it would look and behave nearly exactly as the one you've installed.  And, there's a huge support community should you bump into issues.

Good luck!